Сортировка на Python по кол-ву символов для строки без пробелов
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=open("Nabokov.txt")
x=f.read()
c=[]
b=[' ','(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', ':', ';', '"', "'", '<', '>', ',', '.', '?', '!','-', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] in x:
        x=x.replace(b[i],"")
x=x.upper()
**x = ''.join(sorted(x,))**
print(x)
print(len(x))

a=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
for i in range(26):
    print(x.count(a[i]),"=",a[i],";",(x.count(a[i])/len(x))*100)
    c.append(x.count(a[i]))

sns.barplot(x=a, y=c)
plt.show()

Та строчка которую я выделил сортирует строку. Но сортирует не так ка нужно мне.
Пример [addbddbbggac]
Вывод [ddddbbbggaac]
Это то как мне нужно.
Как сортирует он
Вывод [aabbbcddddgg]
Помогите пожалуйста

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Можете через Counter посчитать кол-во каждого из символов и сгенерить строку заново на основании этого счётчика от самого частого символа до самого редкого. Пример:
from collections import Counter

text = "addbddbbggac"
result = ''.join(ch*cnt for ch,cnt in Counter(text).most_common())
print(result)

Вывод:
ddddbbbaaggc


Можно использовать встроенный метод .count() для сортировки по частотности. И затем пересобрать строку по частоте.
lst = 'addbddbbggac'
st = ''.join(ch * lst.count(ch) for ch in sorted(set(lst), key=lst.count, reverse=True))
print(st)


Плюс - не нужна дополнительная память. Минус - count-у придётся отдельно для каждого уникального символа по всей строке пробежаться, чтобы посчитать символы. Для небольших строк вполне рабочий метод.

@CrazyElf, set(lst) - дополнительная память, такая же как в Counter(lst). Это плохое решение.

@StanislavVolodarskiy А, ну да, это я тупанул. В любом случае count лучше не использовать от слова никогда. Кстати, тут ещё и лишняя переделка в list через comprehension, она избыточна по идее, генератора достаточно.

@CrazyElf компрехеншен убрал, спасибо. А что не так с count? Я не с целью поспорить, а для самообразования.

@AlexeyTrukhanov С использованием set уже не так плохо, но всё-равно count, как я уже писал, должен пробежать всю строку, чтобы посчитать число вхождений символа. И так для каждого уникального символа - нужно проходить всю строку. При том, что можно через Counter (или вручную самому через словарь) собрать статистику сразу по всем символам за один проход по строке. Поэтому count обычно используют только начинающие питонисты.

@CrazyElf благодарю за разъяснение!
